# Draw line with dash results a solid line in Java

Tags: java, awt

I draw a line with [2/3f, 1/3f] dash in Java, but results a solid line.

I also tried other dashs, here is the results:

```
[2/3f, 1/3f]: a solid line
[0.5f, 0.25f]: a good dash line
[0.6f, 0.3f]: a dash line with small difference
[0.66f, 0.33f]: a bad dash line with big difference
[2, 1]: a good dash line
```

Code:

```java
//try width with 1/3f, 0.25f, 0.3f, 0.33f, 1f, different results get.
float width = 1/3f;
float[] dash = new float[] {2*width, 1*width};

BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(600, 600, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
g.setColor(Color.RED);
BasicStroke basicStroke = new BasicStroke(width, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER, 
        10, dash, 0);
g.setStroke(basicStroke);
g.drawLine(0, 300, 600, 300);
g.dispose();

ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", new File("test.png"));
```

Comment: I think this may be aliasing, because the dashes are so short.

Comment: Yes. Notice how 0.3f appears to give you longer dashes than 1f. It's aliasing.

Comment: @tgdavies , width with 0.33f of above code will result an even longer dashes

Comment: The exact effect might depend on your screen resolution too, but it is an aliasing effect.

Answer (score -1):

/* In Java, when you perform 1/3f, the result is zero because both 1 and 3 are integers, and the division is performed using integer arithmetic. To fix this, you need to ensure that you use floating-point values for the dash pattern.
*/
Here's the updated code with the correct float values for the dash pattern:

```
float width = 1f / 3f;
float[] dash = new float[] { 2 * width, width };

BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(600, 600, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
g.setColor(Color.RED);
BasicStroke basicStroke = new BasicStroke(width, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER,
        10, dash, 0);
g.setStroke(basicStroke);
g.drawLine(0, 300, 600, 300);
g.dispose();

try {
    ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", new File("test.png"));
    System.out.println("Image created successfully.");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Remember to adjust the width value as needed to get the desired thickness for the dashed line. The dash array represents the pattern of on and off segments for the dashed line, and you can adjust its values to get different dash patterns.

Comment: `1/3f` is not zero -- did you try it?

Comment: Seems like an AI answer...